# Why my AirDrop device keeps dissapearing?

Tags: file-sharing, airdrop

I am trying to send a file from iPhone to my MacBook via AirDrop. I managed to send first image fine, but when I am trying to send 2nd image my MacBook keeps appearing briefly in iPhone AirDrop list, but then dissapears in less than 1 second. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: To add, it is now keeps blinking all the time. I am even unable to click the icon. Is this hardware issue or software related?